# Injecting services into AngularJS directive controller directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand how Angular dependency injection works with directives but wanted clarification on something. I have a dummy test directive as follows:

```
app.directive("test", [

  function() {

    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {},
      controller: ["$scope", "$filter",
        function($scope, $filter) {
          var food = ["Apple pie", "Apple cobler", "Banana Split", "Cherry Pie", "Applesauce"];

          $scope.favorites = $filter('filter')(food, "Apple");
        }
      ],
      template: "<div>{{favorites}}</div>"
    }
  }
]);
```

This works fine and will filter the `food` array as expected. However I noticed if I inject the `$filter` service in the directive as follows, it still works:

```
app.directive("test", ["$filter",

  function($filter) {

    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {},
      controller: ["$scope",function($scope) {...
```

My question: Is it better practice to inject services into a directive in the declaration line like so:

`app.directive("test", ["$filter", function($filter) {`

or in the controller line like this:

`controller: ["$scope", "$filter", function($scope, $filter) {`?

Is there no difference? Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6aa0fFbEmkPXNeGwa6AC?p=preview) of the directive code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, you're receiving the same service, so it likely doesn't matter too much. I personally prefer to keep them as localized as possible; if you don't need `$filter` in the `link` function or something like that, I'd just inject it into the controller.

In certain cases, this may also make it easier to mock dependencies during testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this also. Much better way by splitting directive and its controller in a single file. Or you can write in separate files. But, better understand

```
app.directive('throbberDirective', 
[   
    function(){
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "common/utils/throbbers/throbber.html",
            controller: throbberController
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('throbberController', throbberController);
throbberController.$inject = ['$scope', '_$ajax'];
function throbberController($scope){
     $scope.throbber = _$ajax.getThrobberConfigs();
     $scope.throbber.templateName = $scope.throbber.templateName;

}
```