# Angular Directive: Dependencies on directive vs dependencies on directive controller

Tags: angularjs

It seems there are [two ways to declare dependencies re: directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Directly on the directive function call -- I'll call it the *"directive directly"* style:

```
.directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {...
```

On the controller option of the directive object **returned** from the function call -- I'll call it the *"directive's controller"* style:

```
controller: ['$scope', function MyTabsController($scope) {...
```

What's the difference? When should I use the "directive directly" style vs the "directive's controller" style?

Here are my guesses:
if I use the "directive directly" style, my dependencies are available to my `link` function.
if I use the "directive's controller" style, the controller allows "inter-directive communication"

So that's my conclusion:

- If you need a controller for "inter-directive communication" ...
- And you don't need the dependencies available in your link function...

Then use the "directive's controller" style...

As I've been (over)thinking Angular lately,  I get confused. For example, I can think of 10 ways to do 1 thing, and spend more time wondering which technique is best than I do actually coding the final solution...

When I get confused , I use these touchstone criteria to make decisions. Maybe you can tell me whether any of these are better served by one or the other. (If you don't agree these are good goals/criterias, or there is no difference re: certain criteria, just ignore them)

- Readability
- Maintainability
- Testability
- Similarity/portability to Angular 2
- Performance

Comment: not apples to oranges. Can't inject `$scope, $element` etc in the outer directive function.

Comment: Do you mean I *am* comparing apples to oranges (false comparison)? Maybe, but please assume I never saw an apple, nor an orange, and I'm trying to learn from documentation which describes them both as "fruits grown on trees". So please teach me how they're different. OK, it's definitely an important difference if some things cannot be injected into the one style, but can be injected into the other.

Comment: Directive deps are for using them in compile and link functions, in rare cases they are used in directive factory function. SInce the introduction of components and controller hooks, link tends to be replaced with controller $postLink hook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injecting services into AngularJS directive controller directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111417/injecting-services-into-angularjs-directive-controller-directly)

Comment: I voted to close, I don't know why I didn't find this duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111417/injecting-services-into-angularjs-directive-controller-directly